# Is there a way to redistribute your stats?

Tags: bloodborne

Is there any way to redistribute your stats in Bloodborne? In Dark Souls 2 you could use souls vessels to do so. Is there anything similar in Bloodborne, or are your decisions final?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a way to respec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not possible.

You can max all stats to 99 though.
Most stats give less attribute boots after 50.